# LocaleDateTime.dayOfWeek return me wrong value

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendarview

I have a calendarView, here's my code

```
binding.calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "$dayOfMonth/$month/$year", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            var selectedDate = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, dayOfMonth, 0, 0)
            val weekdayValue = selectedDate.dayOfWeek.value
            val weekdayName = selectedDate.dayOfWeek.name
        })
```

When I tap on Monday, `weekdayValue` = 5 and `weekdayName` = "Friday".
When I tap on Wednesday, `weekdayValue` = 7 and `weekdayName` = "Sunday".

The first day of week in my calendarView is 2, so Monday.
The Toast show me the good values.

What is the problem ?

Comment: Would be good to see example dates…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CalendarView unfortunately uses 0-based months (January is 0) and LocalDateTime uses 1-based months (January is 1). You need to use `LocalDateTime.of(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth, 0, 0)`.